# ManyToOne JoinColumn (not nullable) not showing form error if `0` submitted with custom form field

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have two classes with a bidirectional relationship: `Player` and `Team` Each player must have exactly one team and each team can have many players.

When I use the default form field (select) and I submit `0` (by manually editing the HTML) the form error shows correctly. However if I use a custom form field type and submit `0` there's no form error but an exception:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   ...\Entity\Player::setTeam() must be an instance of ...\Entity\Team,
>   null given, called in
>   ...\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor.php
>   on line 360 and defined in ...\Entity\Player.php line 58

How do I show a normal form error instead of this exception?

My classes are straighforward (only the relevant parts posted):

Team.php

```
class Team {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="...\Entity\Player", mappedBy="team")
     */
    protected $players;
}
```

Player.php

```
class Player {

    /**
     * @var Team
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="...\Entity\Team", inversedBy="players")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="team_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     * @Assert\Valid
     */
    protected $team;

    /**
     * Set team
     *
     * @param Team $team
     * @return Player
     */
    public function setTeam(Team $team) {
        $this->team = $team;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get team
     *
     * @return Team
     */
    public function getTeam() {
        return $this->team;
    }
}
```

The `reverseTransform` function of my DataTransformer looks like this:

```
public function reverseTransform($value)
{
    if(!$value)
    {
        return $this->multiple ? array() : 0;
    }

    //... get entity
}
```

Comment: What happens if you add @Assert\NotBlank to @Assert\Valid? Or perhaps replace the Valid one with NotBlank? Quick link to the Assert\Valid docs for quick referencing: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html

Comment: So, I've discovered that with the assertions the exception shows only if no value is submitted but the form error shows correctly if I submit 0, which is okay. However with my custom field type the error message never shows even though I'm submitting '0'. I'll adjust the question.

Comment: So, the difference between the default form field and mine is that the default throws a `TransformationFailedException` if the value is invalid. So all I need to know now is how to find out if the field is required from the transformer

Comment: I don't have the time right now, but if it isn't answered this evening I think I can take a detailed look at it :) Thanks for the post-back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have created a custom form field with a custom data transformer, it is your responsibility to validate client datas. To get the generic message (`This value is not valid`), you need to throw a `TransformationFailedException` in your data transformer. Then, everything will be handled by the form component.

EDIT: By default majority of the data transformers in the Symfony core, converts a blank value to `null`. The responsibility of the data transformer is to convert client data to model data and eventually to detect major error like non-acceptable value for a choice list or missing data in case of datetime field, etc. It is not to validate the data which is the resposibility of the validator component. Then, it lets the validator component make the final validation which is often more complex than a simple data transformer. IMHO, you're currently mixing data transfomer and validation concern.

EDIT: Additionally, you need to allow in your domain object what the data transformer return itself (here, the null value).

Comment: I figured that out eventually but I don't know if an empty value is acceptable for the specific property (if the field is required or has some other restrictions)

Comment: That's what I thought and that's why I believed my `reverseTransform` method would work but it doesn't. No matter if I return `0`, `FALSE` or `NULL` I keep getting the same error because it's trying to pass that value to `setTeam`.

Comment: Yes but you domain object is wrong because it should allow a null value. Symfony follows a Java spec for validation (I don't remember the name) but this spec allow to pass invalid value to the object and then validate it. So, you domain object should allow what your transform allows itself (null).

Comment: When I allowed NULL values before there was an 'invalid constraint' exception but now it works, thanks! If you add the part about allowing NULL values to the answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks! 
Mine was an `'entity'` field with `nullable=true`. I solved this by adding a default value `null` to the setter method signaure. `public function setWentBackTo(Activity $wentBackTo = null)`